# setting cookies with HTTPOnly flags in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, cookies, codeigniter-2, xss

I'd like to know how to set cookies as HTTPOnly in Codeigniter. I reviewed the documentation and didn't see how to set this flag.

I was also looking to set the secure flag for cookies and found it in the config.php file:

```
$config['cookie_secure'] = TRUE;
```

But there wasn't an HTTPOnly option in config.php.

How do I set all cookies to HTTPOnly? And if it's done in the framework, it would be helpful to know where that code is for my own learning (and what the default is).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Luckily you can view the source code for [Session.php](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/cdcceecba73dd9f54665f531d15c12f5c9679738/system/libraries/Session.php) on GitHub

In function `_set_cookie` you will see:

```
// Set the cookie
setcookie(
    $this->sess_cookie_name,
    $cookie_data,
    $expire,
    $this->cookie_path,
    $this->cookie_domain,
    $this->cookie_secure,
    $this->cookie_httponly
);
```

The value for `$this->cookie_httponly` is assigned in `__construct` and the default is FALSE but you can set it to TRUE through `config.php` as follows:

```
$config['cookie_httponly'] = TRUE;
```

This will enable your cookies within the framework to be HTTPOnly.

Comment: This no longer works in version 2.1.3 as mentioned in the comment below.

Answer (score 10):

I found that their is a drwaback in session mgmt of codeigniter because

-

1. 2.1.3 version their is no cookie_httponly flag. 
    
   Solution:  
    
   Step 1 :You need to create own My_session.php  in library and extend system session file or modify Session.php (in system->library->Session.php file)  
    
   Step 2: find  _set_cookie($cookie_data = NULL) function, goto  setcookie() and modify as 
   `setcookie( 
           $this->sess_cookie_name, 
           $cookie_data, 
           $expire,

           $this->cookie_path, 
           $this->cookie_domain, 
           $this->cookie_secure, 
           TRUE
   ); // add True flag.`
2. Even though if you are adding "TRUE" and if test with OWASP ZAP tool, 
     some time it ll give you CSRF issues  
    ie: HTTPONLY is not true,  
    Secure flag is not enable. 
     
    
   Reason: Since while sess_destroy they are setting the HTTPONLY and Secure flag to none. 
    
   Solution: Update sess_destroy function in Session.php as

   ```
    // Kill the cookie 
   `setcookie(
             $this->sess_cookie_name,
            addslashes(serialize(array())),
            ($this->now - 31500000),
            $this->cookie_path,
            $this->cookie_domain,
            TRUE,
            TRUE 
        );`
   ```

Since these issues  gave me sleepless nights so I hope this will help you as well. :)

Answer (score 3):

2.1.3 does not contain cookie_httponly in the foreach so it won't set it.

```
foreach (array('sess_encrypt_cookie', 'sess_use_database', 'sess_table_name', 'sess_expiration', 'sess_expire_on_close', 'sess_match_ip', 'sess_match_useragent', 'sess_cookie_name', 'cookie_path', 'cookie_domain', 'cookie_secure', 'sess_time_to_update', 'time_reference', 'cookie_prefix', 'encryption_key') as $key)
```

also it doesn't set here...

```
    setcookie(
                $this->sess_cookie_name,
                $cookie_data,
                $expire,
                $this->cookie_path,
                $this->cookie_domain,
                $this->cookie_secure
            );
```

Comment: I can confirm this in my tests, do you know how it can be set?

Answer (score 0):

This feature does exist now in v2, see this config.php:

> | 'cookie_httponly' = Cookie will only be accessible via HTTP(S) (no javascript)
>
> $config['cookie_httponly']    = TRUE;